# How to calculate a projection matrix for nonnegative constrained least squares?

Tags: least-squares, projection-matrix, quadratic-programming

Suppose we have a data vector **z** in R^p and a training data matrix **X** in R^(p*N), where N (N>p) is the number of samples in the training data matrix.

If we'd like to find the projection of **z** to the linear subspace spanned by the columns of **X**, then we can solve the following unconstrained problem

min  ||**z** - **X** **b**||^2.

The least squared estimation of **b** is (**X** **X**')^-1 **X** **z**. Thus the projection of **z** to the subspace can be written as **X**(**X** **X**')^-1 **X** **z** = **P** **z**. **P** = **X**(**X** **X**')^-1 **X** is a projection matrix satisfying **P**' = **P** and **P**^2 = **P**.

If we add nonnegative constraint to **b**, then the above optimisation problem becomes

min  ||**z** - **X** **b**||^2, s.t. every element in **b** is nonnegative.

The Lagrangian is ||**z** - **X** **b**||^2 - **v**^T **b**, where **v** is an N-dimensional vector. Setting the first order derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t **b** to zero, we find the eistimation of **b**: (**X** **X**')^-1 (**X**' **z** + 1/2 **v**). Thus the projection of **z** to the subspace is **X** (**X** **X**')^-1 (**X**' **z** + 1/2 **v**).

My question now can be described as follows.

Is there any method that can approximate the projection **X** (**X** **X**')^-1 (**X**' **z** + 1/2 **v**) using **P** **z**, where **P** is a projection matrix satisfying **P**' = **P** and **P**^2 = **P**? How can I estimate such **P**?

Thanks in advance!